# Upload project with logged username

Tags: laravel

I dont know how to upload project with the **Logged in user**'s username please help me

```
Project::create([
    'description' => $request->input('description'),
    'division' => $request->input('division'),
    'who' => $request->input('who'),
    'whom' => $request->input('whom'),
    'content' => $request->input('content'),
    'user' => Auth::user()->name ,
    'filename' => $division.'/'.$userName.'/'.$date.'/'.$fileName
]);
```

The error is:

```
General error: 1364 Field 'user' doesn't have a default value
```

[image: This is the error]

model code

`protected $fillable = [ 'description', 'division', 'who', 'whom', 'content', 'filename' ];`

Comment: like this ? `'user' => Auth::user()-&gt;name ,`

Comment: sorry my phone is giving me issues like this `dd(Auth::user()->name)`

Comment: also can you please show the full controller code

Comment: same error sir. it  `General error: 1364 Field 'user' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: you're not doing `dd(Auth::user()->name)` correctly this should show you the username or null

Comment: it gives `"a"` my user name

Comment: can you please show your model code

Comment: `Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('division')->nullable();
            $table->string('who')->nullable();
            $table->string('whom')->nullable();
            $table->string('content')->nullable();
            $table->text('user');
            $table->text('filename');
            $table->timestamps();
        });`

Comment: this is your table migration, not the model

Comment: `protected $fillable = [
        'description',
        'division',
        'who',
        'whom',
        'content',
        'filename'
    ];`

Comment: it looks like i didnt add user in this Model

Comment: you're missing the `'user` in the fillable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163160/discussion-between---and-yosef).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `'user'` in the fillable

try this

`protected $fillable = [ 'description', 'division', 'who', 'whom', 'content', 'user', 'filename' ];`

Comment: now can i remove that dd? what is it can u explain it sir ?

Comment: Yea you can remove it

Comment: also, this is what the dd does `Dump the given variable and end execution of the script.` it will show you everything inside the variable